# What does "on and after" mean in "Her insanity spurred me on and after about two hours I got her to come out"?

Tags: meaning

What does the following sentence mean?

> Her insanity spurred me on and after about two hours I got her to come out.

Does it mean I let her come out after two hours? What exactly does `on and after` mean here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, it is grammatically incorrect without a comma.  It should be:

*Her insanity spurred me on, and after about two hours I got her to come out.*

There are two clauses, separated by a comma.  If you read them in isolation it should make the meaning clear.